# Owl Carousel Trying to remove grey border around nav

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

In owl carousel I have added:

```
navigation:true,
navigationText: ["<img src='img/leftarrow.png'>",
                "<img src='img/rightarrow.png'>"],
```

The images are of two arrows. However, when I view them there is like a grey oval around them? I want to remove this so only the arrow images themselves are visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove outline by adding these styles:

```
.owl-next:focus, .owl-prev:focus {outline: none;}
```

Comment: Where do I add them to, my custom CSS file?

Comment: Yes, to your stylesheet after owl one.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/RNExDqy1PtFbJ1lkRr4I?p=preview there is no outline here. If you can add your styles to this demo it would help to resolve the issue.